# Can't Get response from url powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get response from this url : `https://www.dhl.com/shipmentTracking?AWB=4187598402` which gives json content using Invoke-RestMethod but it keeps loading for lifetime.
I already tried giving useragent like this :
`Invoke-RestMethod $url -Useragent $userAgent` but it's still loading : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnmDg.png

Comment: Some extra info from what I've tried: the first request succeeds and each following request times out. If you relaunch powershell, the first request succeeds once again. Maybe it has something to do with brute force protection at DHL?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue i have. I tried with other website which gives the same json format and it works but not with dhl. I think you are right, is there anything i can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something that is cached or hanging onto the calling PowerShell.exe process. This is why closing PowerShell and reopening fixes the issue. A simple workaround is to just call PowerShell.exe within your session:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www.dhl.com/shipmentTracking?AWB=4187598402'"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well. I achieved what was looking for using your solution.